# How to add support for new "Insertable Streams" feature in current browsers?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I want to encrypt streams before sending to my media server, [like here](https://webrtchacks.com/true-end-to-end-encryption-with-webrtc-insertable-streams/) and [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/endtoend-encryption/).
the problem is they are using very new experimental feature (Insertable Streams), I tried to find a hack to make it work in current browsers. right now the only half way that I've found is to display streams in a canvas and capture altered streams from that canvas [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/capture-stream), but I don't know how to do it and whether it's a right approach or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the API in Chrome for users of your site using a [Chrome origin trial](https://developers.chrome.com/origintrials/#/register_trial/731834939447705601). Origin trials are intended for experimentation. More info about origin trials in general can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/OriginTrials/blob/gh-pages/developer-guide.md).